# Want to allocate space to centos-root folder

Tags: centos, lvm, fdisk, resize2fs

Below is my df -h output

```
[root@dpnjsv2-centos7-base logs]# df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   12G  9.8G  1.6G  87% /
devtmpfs                 2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    2.0G  8.5M  2.0G   1% /run
tmpfs                    2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                497M  148M  350M  30% /boot
/dev/sda1                200M  9.5M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/centos-tmp   2.0G   98M  1.9G   5% /tmp
/dev/mapper/data-data1    50G  1.9G   49G   4% /data1
```

And below is lsblk -f output

```
NAME           FSTYPE    LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
fd0
sda
├─sda1         vfat            4343-0026                              /boot/efi
├─sda2         xfs             7e4e5f1d-6ee5-4e33-8a72-bcd7f227013a   /boot
└─sda3         LVM2_memb       6qx8c7-OfWv-IAYT-GMH0-30EB-yQ61-hKuUMv
  ├─centos-root
               xfs             37835852-3016-4999-9d89-6d6a8ac8a723   /
  ├─centos-swap
               swap            5514e9aa-7131-4956-978d-688409f8c31e   [SWAP]
  └─centos-tmp xfs             2508b082-d9f5-45a8-86dd-425a9ddd56c1   /tmp
sdb
└─sdb1         LVM2_memb       9qQ5c4-vzI5-AMtd-63eU-rG7o-6vkA-T8xLJH
  └─data-data1 xfs             528aa02f-eebd-40ff-8e51-48bddfe6c1cd   /data1
sr0
```

I want to allocate space from data-data1 to centos-root folder a help is appreciated

Comment: `lvreduce` and `lvextend` are your friend. Here is exactly what you need over on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/661101/move-space-from-one-volume-to-other

Comment: I had tried this but it says Xfs filesystem shrinking in unsupported                                                  **lvreduce --resizefs --size -20G /dev/mapper/data-data1
fsadm: Xfs filesystem shrinking is unsupported
  fsadm failed: 1
  Filesystem resize failed.**

Comment: Okay, I see. I don't have much experience with `xfs` filesystems so I might not be much help. Likely involves removing the `--resizefs` and doing the fs resizing piece in a separate, subsequent step.

Comment: Instead of linking off to another site, I will defer to the experts on this one, since I don't  know `xfs` fs that well.

Comment: Thanks.. I m really looking forward for a solution on this

Comment: Might be a good to also add the output of `lsblk -f` to the question which makes it explicit your lvm member fs is of type `xfs`. Best of luck on this; the only other thing I can contribute is to just state – make sure you backup your data before you try anything.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Your `data1` and `root` logical volumes are on two separate volume groups (`data` and `centos` respectively), and volume groups cannot share physical volumes (ex. `sdb1`). XFS aside, if you're willing to place `data1` into your `centos` volume group, then you'd be able to allocate `sdb1` to both logical volumes. Otherwise, ... nope.

Comment: These are two volume groups. LVM does not allow volumes across mulltiple VGs. Why do you have 2 VGs at all? Why not merging them? If you want to add space to a LV - first - is there a free space in VGs? (`vgs`)